# Gradle syncing error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently working on android studio 3.0.2 on ubuntu 17. gradle syncing is creating problem. I tried the working offline and updating SDK.. but none of it worked.

[image]

Comment: The issue seems to be in your 'build.gradle' . can you please share your that file to help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: https://imgur.com/7rr8YVL

Comment: Don't work offline, connect to the network/internet. And share your build.gradle file of a project.

Comment: You can find many of this in StackOverflow. You can try to clear gradle files from project folder. But, there's no guarantee it would work. It would be better to find the problem yourself because there can be many reasons to this problem.

Comment: @harshitdixit try the below answer. It may help you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your **build.gradle(Module: app)** with this:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.goku.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And your **build.gradle(Project: MyApplication)** with this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
     }
   }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Note: Make sure you are connected to internet connection.**
This will work for you.